# Install r5u87x on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, laptop

I need to install Ricoh r5u87x webcam loader on FreeBSD, because it solve not suspending in unix/linux boxes on my vaio laptop as I try it in UBUNTU, but the loader is simply for Linux, I think. Is there any solution for FreeBSD?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Webcam and DVB Compatibility List](http://wiki.freebsd.org/WebcamCompat#line-32) in the FreeBSD wiki, you use [`webcamd`](http://www.selasky.org/hans_petter/video4bsd/) ([available in ports](http://www.freshports.org/multimedia/webcamd/)) to use *a* Ricoh internal webcam under FreeBSD (it doesn't really say which Ricoh webcam is meant; the "built-in Dell E6410").

**What have you tried?**  Maybe the [`r5u87x` userspace tools](https://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x/overview) can even be built under FreeBSD?  (Possibly a combination of `webcamd` and these tools is needed?)